# How to Read data from a large text file and write lines having some string in another using UFT?

Tags: vbscript, qtp, file-handling

I have problem at hand.
I need to read a log file and if any line in the log file contains a specified log level, I need to write that line in a result file.
I have written following code and it is working perfectly.
But my problem is - the size of log file. In my project max size set for a log file is 100 MB. I tested this code with 2 MB - log file (15512 Lines) and it took ridiculously long time (about 1 hour 15 minutes). Also, I am not sure how will this behave with a large file. 
Do you have any other approach? Fast help will be really appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function chekLogFile(sLogFileName, sLogLevelToCheck, sResultFile)
    Dim oFSO, oFile, oResultFileObj, oResultFile
    Dim sFileContent
    Dim arrFileContent
    Dim iNumberOfLinesInFile, iCounter

    ' Open the result file to write
    Set oResultFileObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oResultFile = oResultFileObj.OpenTextFile(sResultFile,8)

    ' Read content from log file
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sLogFileName,1)
    sFileContent = oFile.ReadAll()
    ' Create an array with content of each line as its elements
    arrFileContent = Split(sFileContent,vbcrlf)
    ' Get the number of lines
    iNumberOfLinesInFile = UBound(arrFileContent)

    ' If the line contails the log level, write the line in the result file
    ' The lines we are concereed about start as follows

    ' 20150823135921 :::: ERROR :: 
    ' 20150823135929 :::: WARNING :: 
    ' 20150823135930 :::: INFO :: 

    ' Please note: Any other occurrence of Either of the word except like above will not be counted.

    For iCounter = 0 To iNumberOfLinesInFile Step 1
         If Mid(arrFileContent(iCounter),21,Len(sLogLevelToCheck)) = sLogLevelToCheck Then
            oResultFile.WriteLine(arrFileContent(iCounter))
        End If
    Next

    ' Close the files
    oFile.Close
    oResultFile.Close

    ' Release the objects
    Set oResultFile = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
    Set oResultFileObj = Nothing
End Function


' Log level could be either ERROR OR WARNING OR INFO
Call chekLogFile("E:\UFTTrial\gmail.log", "ERROR", "E:\UFTTrial\ResultFile.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

A text file **is** a collection of strings. If you need to process it sequencially/line by line, slurping the file and then splitting the content into an array is a waste of time and memory. Use .ReadLine() instead.

Sample code applied to a 20 MB file took less than 2 min on my (slow) machine:

```
Option Explicit

Const ForAppending = 8
Const csSrcFile = "M:\lib\kurs0705\testdata\lines.txt"

Dim oFSO : Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim dtStart : dtStart = Now()
checkLogFile csSrcFile, "This", "selected.txt"
Dim dtEnd   : dtEnd   = Now() - dtStart
WScript.Echo oFSO.GetFile(csSrcFile).Size / 10^6, "MB  ", FormatDateTime(dtEnd, vbShortTime)

Public Sub checkLogFile(sLogFileName, sLogLevelToCheck, sResultFile)
    Dim oInFile  : Set oInFile  = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sLogFileName)
    Dim oOutFile : Set oOutFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sResultFile, ForAppending, True)
    Do Until oInFile.AtEndOfStream
       Dim sLine : sLine = oInFile.ReadLine()
       If Mid(sLine, 1, Len(sLogLevelToCheck)) = sLogLevelToCheck Then
          oOutFile.WriteLine sLine
       End If
    Loop
    oInFile.Close
    oOutFile.Close
End Sub
```

output:

```
cscript readlog.vbs
20,888896 MB   00:01
```

Comment: @ Ekkehard: I did try it like below but still it is taking a long time:  
`code`
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sLogFileName,1)
    
    Do while oFile.AtEndOfStream <> true
     sLineContent =  oFile.ReadLine  
     If Mid(sLineContent,21,Len(sLogLevelToCheck)) = sLogLevelToCheck Then
      oResultFile.WriteLine(sLineContent)
     End If
    Loop

Answer (score 0):

The physical size of the file isn't the important aspect; the number of lines in the file is. The higher the line count, the longer it's going to take to use .ReadLine()

Ekkehard's answer is pretty much verbatim to what I was going to write. Keep in mind that a file with 2,000 lines and 200 characters/line will be read significantly faster than a 20,000 lines and 20 character/line file. How many lines are in the file you're trying to parse?